# Retornar consulta com mais de 1 parâmetro no WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api

Tenho o código abaixo, como ficaria a route correta?
Como eu posso testar a chamada

```html
        //http://localhost:1608/api/ApiCidade/consulta/clienteLoginSenha/
        [HttpGet]
       // [Route("consulta/clienteLoginSenha/{email:long}/{senha:long}")]
        [Route("consulta/clienteLoginSenha/email{email}/senha/{senha}")]
        public HttpResponseMessage ClientePorLoginSenha(string email, string senha)
        {
            try
            {
                var tCliente = new ClienteAplicacao();
                var listarDeClientes = tCliente.ListarPorLoginSenha(email,senha);
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, listarDeClientes.ToArray());
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex.Message);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Como você quer que seja a rota? Qual erro que você está encontrando atualmente?

Comment: Fiz um teste com as duas rotas que estou colocando na pergunta, as duas gera um erro

Comment: Qual o erro que retorna? tenta detalhar mais

Comment: a rota ficou assim : [Route("consulta/clienteLoginSenha/{email}/{senha}")]
é para testar : http://localhost:1608/api/ApiCidade/consulta/clienteLoginSenha/teste@teste.com.br/teste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A resposta:

```
a rota ficou assim : 
[Route("consulta/clienteLoginSenha/{email}/{senha}")]
é para testar : http://localhost:1608/api/ApiCidade/consulta/clienteLoginSenha/teste@teste.com.br/teste
```